# julia mysql.jl use non default port

Tags: mysql, julia

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using the mySQl.jl package.  it seems to work fine when I'm using the standard mySQL port 3306, but I don't see where to specify a database on a different port.  How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help doc of `mysql_connect` (get it with `?mysql_connect` at the REPL):

> ```
> mysql_connect(host::String, user::String, passwd::String, 
>   db::String = ""; port::Int64 = MYSQL_DEFAULT_PORT, 
>   socket::String = MYSQL_DEFAULT_SOCKET, opts = Dict())
> ```
>
> Connect to a MySQL database.

So just add a named parameter `port=` after the database name parameter. For example:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "john", "password", "my_db", port=1234)
```

Comment: I did already try that, and I get this error   ERROR: MethodError: no method matching mysql_connect(::String, ::String, ::String, ::String, ::Int64)

Comment: Hmm... which package version do you have on `MySQL.db` ? check with `Pkg.status("MySQL")`

Comment: julia> Pkg.status("MySQL")
 - MySQL                         0.1.0

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed the `;` in the parameter list, which means it is a named parameter. You have to go `mysql_connect("host", "user", "passwd", "db", port=1234)`. I'll update the answer